# Identifying Video on a webpage

Tags: firefox, video, xul

I am trying to code a Firefox extension, that can get the video (youtube/vimeo) property (path, etc.) when a user right-clicks on it on a web page.

The problem, i see is right-click brings menu system native to the player.

Any pointer would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the video player is using flash which reside inside the flash embeded object. This object has nothing to do with XUL and cannot be manipulated with by any extension in firefox. What you really are trying to do is to make an extension to flash which you cannot.

The only possible solution I can see is to override the flash object itself with an XUL "stack" object and have the original flash object as a child to the stack object.